# Manga where a guy is reincarnated into a fantasy game; he collects scrolls to get power before the kingdom falls

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

A guy is reincarnated into a fantasy game, maybe an RPG. He collects scrolls to get power before the kingdom falls. He also has a glider he made using magic. He gets blessed by a wind god for helping a dragon. He also goes to an elf village.

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[Villager A Wants to Save the Villainess No Matter What!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/chounin-a-wa-akuyaku-reijou-wo-doushitemo-sukuitai)***...?

> Allen, an eight-year-old boy from a poor family in the royal capital, is living a poor but happy life together with his mother. One day, however, memories of his previous life suddenly come back to him and he remembers that he is in an dating sim game and that the capital will be destroyed by war if he doesn’t do something about it. If this continues, both he and his mother will be killed! With a sense of urgency, he decides to rise to the occasion in order to save his precious mother’s life and save his favorite character, the villainous young lady Anastasia, the only girl he liked in the game, from her all too tragic and ruinous end.

An aeronautical engineer is reincarnated as Allen, a young boy in the world of a smartphone game he'd been playing.

He wants to change the storyline of the game, since he knows that the city he lives in will be otherwise be destroyed as the result of a coming civil war and invasion.

In chapter 2, he starts hunting for scrolls in various locations; each scroll he finds grants him a new skill, such as 'Concealment' and 'Appraisal.'

In chapter 5, the Wind God offers to give Allen his divine protection if he'll help a wyvern lord named Jerome get married to his dream girl, a sky dragon named Melissa.

> [image: Villager A Wants to Save the Villainess No Matter What!, chapter 5, page 21.]

In chapter 6, Allen uses knowledge from his past life and alchemy magic to design and build a glider.

> [image: Villager A Wants to Save the Villainess No Matter What!, chapter 6, page 19.]

In chapter 8, he's captured by a group of armed elves and taken to their village to be questioned by their leader.